# Syntax error in Kivy Pong tutorial

Tags: python, syntax-error, kivy

I've started the Kivy tutorial from their website. Been following the starting code and I've run in to a syntax error. I've searched a lot for an answer, but none of them don't apply for my situation.

The python file is named 'PongApp.py':

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Sep  7 21:16:31 2017

@author: 917k
"""

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class PongGame(Widget):
    pass

class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PongGame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

I've also made a .kv file that's called 'Pong.kv' and it's in the same directory as 'PongApp.py'.

Pong.kv:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#:kivy 1.10.0

<PongGame>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x = -5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"
```

The error message:

```
pos: self.center_x = -5, 0
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've read through the note about naming the .kv file on Kivy's tutorial website and I think I understood it correctly. I suspect there might be an indentation or naming error somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is typo error in your kv file. Replace

```
pos: self.center_x = -5, 0
```

with

```
pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
```

## Example

### pong.kv

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#:kivy 1.10.0

<PongGame>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"
```

### PongApp.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class PongGame(Widget):
    pass


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PongGame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#:kivy 1.10.0

<PongGame>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x = - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"
```

I think you need a space inbetween ( pos: self.center_x = -"here"5, 0) and I have updated the code above so try running it once more

Comment: I'll try it later in the day and check if that worked.